# SharedPreferences doesn't work between packages (within one app)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a app which contains two packages. In the package com.soul.app1.plugin there is a FireReceiver.class (this is a part of the Tasker plugin). Value is stored fine, but it is retrieved correctly (in the second package - Settings.class) only for the first time I run it (after reinstall). When I try to retrieve it again the old value is retrieved instead of new one.

Settings.java in com.soul.app1 package:

```
public class Settings extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onResume()  {
    super.onResume();

     SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
     int minVolSet = settings.getInt("value", 0);   
    }

}
```

FireReceiver.java in com.soul.app1.plugin package:

```
public final class FireReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

   @Override
   public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
   {
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
     SharedPreferences settings;
    settings = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putInt("value", 2); // constant 2 is for testing purposes only
    editor.apply();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've sloved the problem by switching `getSharedPreferences()` to the `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS. So:

```
getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
```

to

```
getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 4);
```

The key to understand this is the fact that every package (even within the same app) has its own process.I couldn't find this information so I had to learn it on my own :).

Comment: Normally all components of an app will run in a single process, unless requested otherwise.  However, it is possible that similar factors might be an issue when multiple *threads* are involved, something the documentation neglects to comment on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to commit the editor after applying the new values

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
     SharedPreferences settings;
    settings = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    editor.putInt("value", 2); // constant 2 is for testing purposes only
    editor.commit()
```

Comment: The apply() does exactly the same. As I said the "value" is stored correctly (I've checked it).

Comment: so when you reinstall the application. preference are getting cleared and the default value is returned i guess.

Comment: and you are setting values as 2 every time so how can we verify for the new value?

Comment: I'm changing the value via seekBar, but I've simplified the code for a purpose of this post. I think problem might be because I'm working between packages.

Comment: make sure that you are getting correct value from seekbar. since preference code looks good and I am sure it's not problem with packages

Answer (score -1):

For editing in shared Preference `editor.commit()` is required.

Comment: The `apply()` does exactly the same. As I said the "value" is stored correctly (I've checked it).